# html divider border not properly including all subcontents

Tags: html, css

First time trying to make an HTML/CSS Django website, thank you for the patience. I'm working from a simple resume template and trying to fix an error I found from the start (template in question https://github.com/resume/resume.github.com/tree/47aba3b380459c07967b4f38c9e77fbe42be07a6).

I have a section of my section of my website with the following visual error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/55fgP.jpg). The 1px thick section divider line is being placed below the headings rather than after the full content of the section. This is not an issue for other sections of the website, but the stacked, non line-by-line elements like these two sections have issues.

The html section is

```
                   <div class="yui-gf">
                        <div class="yui-u first">
                            <h2>Skills</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="yui-u">
                                <div class="talent">
                                    <h2>Multi-System Design</h2>
                                    <p>Proven experience with robotic systems spanning mechanical, electrical, and software backgrounds.</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="talent">
                                    <h2>Interpersonal Reporting</h2>
                                    <p>Familiarity with reporting, documentation, and organization of technical design documents.</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="talent">
                                    <h2>Problem Based Solutions</h2>
                                    <p>Involvement with team based, problem driven projects that solve a question rather than a set task.</p>
                                </div>

                        </div><!--// .yui-u -->
                    </div><!--// .yui-gf -->

                    <div class="yui-gf">
                        <div class="yui-u first">
                            <h2>Technical</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="yui-u">
                            <ul class="talent">
                                <li>SolidWorks</li>
                                <li>Autodesk Inventor</li>
                                <li class="last">Autodesk Eagle</li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="talent">
                                <li>MATLAB</li>
                                <li>Python 3</li>
                                <li class="last">ROS</li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="talent">
                                <li>SimTK OpenSim</li>
                                <li>SimTK SCONE</li>
                                <li class="last">Lua</li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="talent">
                                <li>Microsoft Word</li>
                                <li>Microsoft PowerPoint</li>
                                <li class="last">Microsoft Excel</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--// .yui-u-->
                    </div><!--// .yui-gf-->
```

And the CSS section is

```
.yui-gf {
margin-bottom: 2em;
padding-bottom: 2em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

.last {
    border: none;
}

.skills-list {  }

.skills-list ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.skills-list li {
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

.skills-list li span {
    font-size: 152%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    padding: 0
}

.talent {
    width: 32%;
    float: left
}

.talent h2 {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* --// override to force 1/8th width grids -- */
.yui-gf .yui-u{width:80.2%;}
.yui-gf div.first{width:12.3%;}
```

I'm sort of stumped as to why the spacing+divider is being applied after the heading class, even though the yui-gf divider encompasses all the elements (heading class, talent class, written content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating of `.talent` is most likely the culprit. When floating elements the parent looses track of their height, so if you check the dev tools you will most likely find out the divs with the class `yui-gf` are actually ending there.

Remove the floating and width of the `.talent` and try using [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) on the parent to align its childs in columns.

```
.yui-u {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

Or:

```
.yui-u {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 32% 32% 32%;
}
```

Also, the `.yui-gf` class in your CSS definition you pasted here is missing the closing curly bracket.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will move forward from there.